# SQL Server 2017 undetected deadlock issue

Tags: sql, deadlock, sql-server-2017

The problem is:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT TOP 1 
    q.*               ) 
FROM [QTable] q WITH(UPDLOCK) 
WHERE <some condition>
ORDER BY <some columns>
```

This is called by a dozen of concurrent processes every few seconds each. After this select they make stuff by 1-2 seconds then make a single update of this very selected row and end their sessions with commit (rollback is also possible but never observed).

Table `QTable` currently has 350'000 rows but the job is around its top (it has an identity column as a primary key). The table is fed periodically with some new rows by the single insert statement (under transaction, as the another table must be updated because of new rows added to `QTable`).

It has been working for last 5 years smoothly but last time THEY (means IT stuff) updated SQL Server to 2017. And the tragedy appeared immediately: all processes get blocked very fast -- some of them (1-2) are on locks, while all others are waiting for CXPACKET.

When we analyse deeply it looks as they are waiting cycles -- classic deadlock.

We changed updlock into tablockx and it works again, but my question is why? We have a lot of concurrent updlock access, but rather rare, but we are afraid that all of our SQL will crash for the very same reason.

My suspicion is the `ORDER BY` clause is responsible for that, but what has been changed in SQL Server that corrupted its many-years perfect behaviour?

Comment: do you have access to logs? they might tell you what happened. 
I'd *guess* that some metadata (index? cache?) got corrupted, and changing the table caused it to be refreshed / recalculated.

Comment: On which object deadlock occur - on base table (clustered index) or some other index? We have got increasing load of deadlocks either (on defferent SQL versions), we suspect some index page splitting on inserts - this escalates page locks to multiple pages. Quite nasty to debug.

Comment: As we changed updlock to tablockx everything runs smooth again, although there are some aspects where we can observe substantial performance slow down. The table oryginally had only PK clustered index because of identity column.
My plan is to add an index containing all columns used in my ORDER BY clause as well as in WHERE clause with adequate column order. Then I suppose the SELECT TOP 1 (with index hint) will read only a single table page each time and only few index entries and locks will not escalate.